# Consul Config and Discovery - Read-only key-value-store, write rights for services

Tags: security, acl, consul, service-discovery

I want to use Consul for Service Discovery and as Distributed Configuration for my microservices. Without any security my system is working fine but I don't want every user to be able to change values in the key-value store. So I tried to introduce security with Consul's ACL but now my services aren't able to register themselves anymore.

I set the default policy in my HCL configuration to "deny" and tried to set a write policy for every service so they can register themselves at Consul and a read policy for the key-value-store, so the values can only be read via the UI. But my services receives a 403 during registration process.

agent.hcl

```
service_prefix "" {
  policy = "write"
}
key_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}
```

consul-policy.hcl

```
service_prefix "" {
  policy = "write"
}
key_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}
```

I started the server with:

```
consul agent -config-file agent.hcl -dev
```

And added the policy (after getting and setting an ACL token):

```
consul acl policy create -name consul-server-one -rules @consul-policy.hcl
```

1. How can I define a read-only policy for the key-value store in the UI and a write policy for services?
2. Is it possible to start Consul with the ACL configuration (instead of delivering it after the startup process)?
3. Which ACL resources are the right ones for my problem? Are service_prefix and key_prefix correct choices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did miss was the fact that you need to generate tokens for a policy.

```
consul acl token create -description "Token description" -policy-name "consul-server-one" -token "(your global token)"
```

And I wanted the usage of a default token which can be set via:

```
consul acl set-agent-token -token "(your global token)" default (your generated token)
```